# volume of a cylindrical shell

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Find in cylindrical coordinates the volume of a object that is above the surface $z=\sqrt[4]{x^2 + y^2}$ and inside $x^2 +y^2 + z^2 =2$.

We use $$V=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\int_0^{z^2} 1 rdrdzd\phi+\int_0^{2\pi}\int_1^{\sqrt{2}}\int_0^{\sqrt{2-z^2}} 1 rdrdzd\phi$$
$$V=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 \frac{z^4}{2} dzd\phi+\int_0^{2\pi}\int_1^{\sqrt{2}}\frac{2-z^2}{2}dzd\phi$$
$$V=\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{10} d\phi+\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}-\frac 56d\phi$$
$$V=\frac{\pi}{5}+\frac{4\pi\sqrt{2}}{3}-\frac{5\pi}{3} $$

Comment: What are the equations of these surfaces in cylindricals?  What is the expression for an element of volume in cylindricals?  Where do the surfaces intersect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The region could be divided into two regions and
$$V=\int\int\int_D 1dV=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\int_0^{z^2} rdrdzd\theta+\int_0^{2\pi}\int_1^\sqrt2\int_0^\sqrt{2-z^2} rdrdzd\theta$$

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but can you give me some insight on how did you determine the limits for the 3 (or 6 in this case) integrals? :)

Comment: @ELEC i have edited it, i added a section of the graph. Moreover you reverse the order of the integral element to be $rdzdrd\theta$

Comment: Hmmm why reverse the order? The two part integral you provided doesn't give the right answer?

Comment: Both should give the same value. revise your calculations

Comment: Yeah, thanks! :) The picture you provided really helped me to understand.

Comment: Glad to help out @ELEC

Comment: I checked the integral. shouldn't there be a minus on the first integral? so you subtract the first integral from the second.

Comment: first $2\pi/10$ , second $4\pi\sqrt{2}/3$

Comment: second is incorrect

Comment: it sould be $\pi[4\sqrt2/3-5/3]$

Comment: Hmmm i did the integral, but my answer is a little off... See my og post

Comment: write down the right answer there as a comment

Comment: $V=\frac{\pi}{5}+\frac{4\pi\sqrt{2}}{3}-\frac{5\pi}{3} $. somehow I m stuck with that first term :D

Comment: I mean that one you expect. The first and the last are $-22\pi/15$

Comment: now i'm confused, can you edit my post where i did my work?

Comment: Ahhhh. So it got it right :D. I just thought you meant the full answer was $\pi[4\sqrt{2}/3-5/3]$